# Problem with while loop in Python, repeating string

Tags: python, while-loop, helper

```
a = input('Enter your username...')
while (a == 'SuperGiraffe007&'):
  print('Welcome!')
else:
  print("Try again...")
a = input('Enter your username...')
while (a == 'SuperGiraffe007&'):
  print('Welcome!')
```

- The code functions correctly but when I input the correct username the string 'Welcome!' repeats forever which crashes my browser. How do I stop it from repeating and only print once?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have misunderstood what a `while` loop does. It checks the condition you give it and keeps on repeating the body of the loop for as long as the condition is true. The infinite loop you describe is exactly what you're asking for with your code.

What I think you want is a loop that *stops* when the user enters the correct username:

```
a = input('Enter your username...')
while a != 'SuperGiraffe007&': # stop looping when the name matches
    print("Try again...")
    a = input('Enter your username...') # ask for a new input on each loop
print('Welcome!')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use `if` instead of `while`. Also, you don't need the parenthesis when using a conditional in python.
Use this:

```
a = input('Enter your username...')
if a == 'SuperGiraffe007&':
  print('Welcome!')
else:
  print("Try again...")
a = input('Enter your username...')
if (a == 'SuperGiraffe007&'):
  print('Welcome!')
```